# Trouble accessing Google Drive from file manager

Tags: unity, 16.04, gnome, cinnamon, google-drive

In response to possible duplicate question: I am trying to get access to my Google Drive files via the file manager. I am **not** trying to find and install a Google Drive client. I'm just talking about being able to access my Google Drive files from the files manager. I understand that this means no sharing links and the like.

I'm running the Cinnamon desktop environment on Ubuntu 16.04. I have followed all instructions to install Gnome Control Center and Online Accounts. It appears my Online Accounts has connected to the Unity Control Center, but when I try to run

```
~$ gnome-control-center online-accounts
```

To access my Online Accounts settings, I get these warnings:

```
** (gnome-control-center:5834): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher gufw (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:5834): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher landscape-client-settings (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:5834): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher ubuntuone-installer (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:5834): WARNING **: Could not find settings panel "online-accounts"
```

I have already gone through and installed Gnome Control Center and rebooted. If I use the sudo apt-get to try and install it again, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-control-center is already the newest version (1:3.18.2-   1ubuntu6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I'm rather new to Linux in general, but I've searched high and low and nothing has shown me anything beyond the basic how-to install Gnome Control Center bits. I have no idea why the terminal wouldn't be able to find what it needed. Please let me know if you need any more information about my setup. Like I said, I'm rather new, so I don't know what would be helpful.

EDIT:

I found an answer elsewhere that answered my question. I needed to run the command under the Gnome desktop, I guess? by adding:

```
sudo XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center
```

It worked flawlessly.

Comment: There is this guide http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/use-google-drive-ubuntu-16-04-linux-desktops, as well as one more with nearly identical information